# How to show Android Media Controls?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

**How can I implement android media controls for the Notification Center when using `MediaPlayer`?**

I tried to use the [offical documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-controls) right here and [this article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/playing-nicely-with-media-controls.html) but I couldn't implement it correctly.

[image]

I tried to call this method when I start my media player `mediaPlayer?.start()`, but nothing is showing up in the notification center:

```kotlin
val mSession: MediaSession by lazy { MediaSession(requireContext(), "MusicService") }

fun createMediaControls() {
    mSession.isActive = true
    mSession.setCallback(object : MediaSession.Callback() {
        override fun onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent: Intent): Boolean {
            print("onMediaButtonEvent called: $mediaButtonIntent")
            return false
        }

        override fun onPause() {
            print("onPause called (media button pressed)")
            super.onPause()
        }

        override fun onPlay() {
            print("onPlay called (media button pressed)")
            super.onPlay()
        }

        override fun onStop() {
            print("onStop called (media button pressed)")
            super.onStop()
        }
    })
    mSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS or MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS)

    mSession.setMetadata(
        MediaMetadata.Builder()
            .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "titleee")
            .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "artist")
            .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI, "albumArtUri")
            .build()
    )
}
```

Comment: perhaps posting what you tried and what specifically didn't work would provide more context on what you are trying to do and what you did. All this correlated with what you want would provide more insight to see what you need.

Comment: @JoxTraex Thank you. Check the question again please

Comment: Usually you have to set the media session in your `MediaBrowserCompatService` like they do in UAMP here: https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/8dda0e8d3cb4ec9d4422fb40b02ea65bfd3f1b6c/common/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/media/MusicService.kt#L180

If you include how you're using your session and not just how you create it we could probably help out more.

Comment: @Ann-Sofi I only have the code I showed you in the question. I'm new to Mediasession and I don't know how to start implementing media controls. It would be good if you could show me how to start using it. In the uamp app i can figure out how it works without having the same classes as they have etc.